# How to automatically add the character _ into a string or list which is input by a user to make 2 lists the same length

Tags: python, list

```
string1 = str(input("STRING 1: "))
string2 = str(input("STRING 2: "))


difference = 0

print(string1)
print(string2)


for i in string2:
    if len(string1) < len(string2):
        difference = len(string2) - len(string1)
        difference = difference*"-"
        string2 = string2.append(difference)
for i in string1:        
    if len(string2) < len(string1):
        difference = len(string1) - len(string2)
        difference = difference*"-"
        string1 = string1.append(difference)

        
print(string1)
print(string2)
```

#for loop to find longest string
#and what the difference in string length
#apend the character "-"to the end of the shoter string to make the 2 strings the same length
# eg. johnjones
#   mary-----

Comment: It is not clear whether `string1` and `string2` are supposed string or list. Since coming from user are strings. But why are you on list too?

Comment: You can solve this using string-formatting, which also would have the added benefit to not edit the `string1`or `string2` variables. `"{:-<{}}".format(x, len(max([x,z], key=lambda c: len(c))))` replace `x` and `z` with your strings that you want to print.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string1 = str(input("STRING 1: "))
string2 = str(input("STRING 2: "))

difference = 0

print(string1)
print(string2)

for i in string2:
    if len(string1) < len(string2):
        difference = len(string2) - len(string1)
        difference = difference * "-"
        string1 = string1 + difference
for i in string1:
    if len(string2) < len(string1):
        difference = len(string1) - len(string2)
        difference = difference * "-"
        string2 = string2 + difference

print(string1)
print(string2)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use for.

append is the function of list.

You should declare a list.

Or you use += .

```py
string1 = str(input("STRING 1: "))
string2 = str(input("STRING 2: "))

difference = 0

result_list = list()

if len(string1) < len(string2):
    difference = len(string2) - len(string1)
    difference = difference * "-"
    string1 += difference
    result_list.append(string2 + difference)
    
if len(string2) < len(string1):
    difference = len(string1) - len(string2)
    difference = difference * "-"
    string2 += difference
    result_list.append(string2 + difference)
    

print(result_list)
print(string1)
print(string2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the methods:

```
string1 = str(input("STRING 1: "))
string2 = str(input("STRING 2: "))

difference = 0

print(string1)
print(string2)

if len(string1) < len(string2):
    difference = len(string2) - len(string1)
    for i in range(difference):
        string1 +="-"
elif len(string2) < len(string1):
    difference = len(string1) - len(string2)
    for i in range(difference):
        string2 +="-"
    
print(string1)
print(string2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using string-formatting and the max-function we can dynamically "pad" the shorter string:

```
string1 = "johnjones"
string2 = "mary"
strList = [string1, string2]
print("{:-<{}}".format(string1, len(max(strList, key=lambda x: len(x)))))
print("{:-<{}}".format(string2, len(max(strList, key=lambda x: len(x)))))
#Output: johnjones
#Output: mary-----
```

The variables `string1` and `string2` are not changed using the above code, just their representation in the output.

You can read more about the syntax of string-formatting [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

However, this is a short explainer of what the different parts mean in the above code:

- `{}` is a `replacement-field`, this is the location that the `str.format` method tries to input it's variables into.
- `:` placed inside of a `replacement-field` is called a `format-specifier` which tells `str.format` how to handle the variable.
- `-` in the expression `{:-<{}}` is the `fill`-character that should be used in the formatting.
- `<` is the text-alignment of the string. `<` means that the text is anchored to the left, `>` is anchored to the right, and `^` centers the text.
- `{}` inside of the expression `{:-<{}}` is just another `replacement-field` that will be populated by `str.format`, in this case however, it refers to `width` of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why are referring to list, but, from what I can understand, you could just do something like this:

```
delta = len(str1) - len(str2)
if delta < 0:
    str1 += '_'*abs(delta)
else:
    str2 += '_'*abs(delta)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - appreciated